# SwiftGen - multiple outputs each from a separate strings input

Tags: ios, swift, swiftgen

I have two `.strings` files in Xcode project, say: `First.strings` and `Second.strings`, and would like SwiftGen to generate a separate `.swift` file for each of them — one with contents of `First.strings` file and second with the contents of `Second.strings` file.

How should I configure the `swiftgen.yml` file under `strings:` param so that it knows how to do that? I wanted to avoid running the SwiftGen script twice.

Comment: Have you tried to add `strings:
  paths: YourPath/First.strings
  output: FirstStrings.swift` for each file ?

Comment: Yes — doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen/blob/stable/Documentation/ConfigFile.md#configuration-file-format) on constructing the swiftgen

```yaml
xcassets:
  - inputs: Foo/Assets.xcassets
    outputs:
      - templateName: swift5
        output: Foo/Resources/Assets.swift

  - inputs: SwiftPackages/Foo/Sources/Foo/Assets/Assets.xcassets
    outputs:
      - templateName: swift5
        output: SwiftPackages/Foo/Sources/Foo/Assets/Assets.swift
```

The above configuration gives the expected result. You can verify it by running `swiftgen --verbose`. The above example uses xcassets but you can do it with strings as well.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```yaml
    strings:
        inputs:
            - First.strings
        outputs:
            output: FirstOutput.swift
    
        inputs:
            - Second.strings
        outputs:
            output: SecondOutput.swift
```

Comment: Only last inputs item will be processed